# Integral on a rotational solid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, rotations, multiple-integral

> Compite the integral $$\int_V\frac{4-z^2}{(x^2+y^2)^3}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz,$$ where $V$ is the solid enclosed by the paraboloids $x^2+y^2=z,x^2+y^2=2z$ and cones $x^2+y^2=(z-2)^2,x^2+y^2=4(z-2)^2.$

**My attempt:**

$V$ is a rotational solid with $z$ axis as the axis of the rotation. Two cones have picks at the same point above the vertex of the parabolae. I decided to use cyllindrical coordinates: $$\begin{aligned}x&=r\cos\varphi\\y&=r\sin\varphi\\z&=z\\\varphi&\in[0,2\pi].\end{aligned}$$
The Jacobian of the transformation is then $J_\psi(\varphi,r)=r$ and the function under the integral becomes $\frac{4-z^2}{r^6}.$

I thought I should first compute the integral on the solid enclosed by the parabolae and the cone $x^2+y^2=(z-2)^2$ and subtract the integral on the solid enclosed by the parabolae and the cone $x^2+y^2=4(z-z^2).$

Now, I wanted to find the radii of the circles -intersections of the parabolae with cones $x^2+y^2=(z-2)^2$ and $x^2+y^2=4(z-2)^2$ for the first and second integral respectively. Solving $$\begin{cases}x^2+y^2=z\\x^2+y^2=(z-2)^2\end{cases}\\\begin{cases}x^2+y^2=2z\\x^2+y^2=(z-2)^2\end{cases}$$ yields the bounds $r=1,r=2,r=\sqrt{2(3\pm\sqrt 5)}$ and $$\begin{cases}x^2+y^2=z\\x^2+y^2=4(z-2)^2\end{cases}\\\begin{cases}x^2+y^2=2z\\x^2+y^2=4(z-2)^2\end{cases}$$ yields the bounds $r=\sqrt{\frac{17\pm\sqrt{33}}8},\sqrt{2\frac{9\pm\sqrt{17}}4}
$

The first integral I get is

$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^{\sqrt{2(3-\sqrt 5)}}\int_{2-r}^r\frac{4-z^2}{r^5}\mathrm dz\mathrm dr\mathrm d\varphi+\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\sqrt{2(3-\sqrt 5)}}^2\int_{r^2/2}^r\frac{4-z^2}{r^5}\mathrm dz\mathrm dr\mathrm d\varphi+\int_0^{2\pi}\int_2^{\sqrt{2(3+\sqrt 5)}}\int_{r^2/2}^{2+r}\frac{4z-z^2}{r^5}\mathrm dz\mathrm dr\mathrm d\varphi$ and I would analogously write the second integral, but the numbers I got don't seem quite operable. Am I missing something and is there a more efficient method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D_-=\{(r,z): r\geq 0, z\leq 2, z\leq r^2\leq 2z, (z-2)^2\leq r^2\leq 4(z-2)^2\}$, and consider the following change of variables: $u=z/r^2$ and $v=(z-2)^2/r^2$, then
$$\left|\det\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}& \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}& \frac{\partial v}{\partial z}
\end{pmatrix}\right|=2\frac{4-z^2}{r^5}
.$$
Then
$$\iiint_{V\cap \{z\leq 2\}}\frac{4-z^2}{(x^2+y^2)^3} dx dy dz=2\pi\iint_{D_-}\frac{4-z^2}{r^6}rdrdz=
2\pi\int_{u=1/2}^1\int_{v=1/4}^1\frac{1}{2}dudv=\frac{3\pi}{8}.$$

Comment: Oh, I should've done that as I used to in $2$-D. This question was from the old exam and the hint (somewhere below the task) was to notice the solid is a rotational one so I thought I was supposed to do something with the given solids explicitly. Thank you! The answer is clear.

Comment: I do not think this is correct, as there is a region bound above $z = 2$ as well. You seem to have ignored that.

Comment: @MathLover Yes, I evaluated the integral in the region below $z=2$. The integral over  the other piece should be of opposite value.

Comment: @MathLover, so we should take into account only the part below the 'lower cone'?

Comment: @Winter Actually, according to the given statement, $V$ has two connected components: one below $z=2$ and the other above. My computation is for the part below $z=2$. The other one yields in a similar way the opposite value. So the integral over $V$ should be zero.

Comment: @Winter Do you have the official answers of this old exam?

Comment: The solutions have been posted only since 2018/2019, so I don' t have it, but in some tasks, when the cone had the tip in the origin, it said we considered only the part below the plane, so I believe it would've been written. I understand your answer, so I'm going to ask on the exam and future exercises what're required and what is their convention (I tried to cover theory and practice in advance). Thank you once again. It helped a lot.

Comment: @Winter OK, anyway you have the answer in both cases.